# $f: E \to E$ by $f(x) = x^p, \forall x \in E$. Then $f$ is an injective ring homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding what a characteristic is and I need it to solve the following. Let $E$ be a field of characteristic $p$ $f: E \to E$ by $f(x) = x^p, \forall x \in E$. Then $f$ is an injective ring homomorphism. In particular, if $|E| = p^n$ for some $n\in \Bbb N$ then $f$ is an automorphism of $E$.

So ideally, I need to show that $f(xy) = (xy)^p = x^p y^p = f(x)f(y)$ and

if $f(x) = f(y)$ implies that $x = y$ where  $f(x)= x^p = y^p = f(y)$. So then $x^p = y^p$ so $x = y$.

My book never bothered to define characteristic but having looked it up, I'm getting many different complicated definitions of it. I think I can finish this if I know exactly what the characteristic is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @A.G sorry $E$ is a field of characteristic $p$. Ill edit the question.

Comment: The only non trivial step is to show that $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$. Do you know how to prove it? Once you have that it is a homomorphism, the injectivity, and bijectivity in the finite case, follow from general facts (you do not need characteristic $p$).

Comment: @A.G I actually do not. How would I go about doing that? I would have to show that all the other terms aside from $x^p, y^p$ are equal to zero right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are working with unitary rings then every field homomorphism is injective. So you only need to prove that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$. Since $E$ is a field, $xy=yx$, thus $(xy)^p=x^{p}y^{p}$. On the other hand $(x+y)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}x^{k}y^{p-k}$, and because $p|\binom{p}{k}$ and $char(E)=p$ we deduce that $\binom{p}{k}x^{k}y^{p-k}=0$ for all $1\le k\le p-1$. Therefore $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$.

Comment: Ok. I see. I was missing the part where all the terms are 0 because p is characteristic. Thank you very much.

Comment: Exactly, if $char(E)=n$ and $n|m$, then $ma=0$ for all $a\in E$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use binomial formula to expand like
$$
(x+y)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p\binom {p}{k}x^{p-k}y^k
$$
Prove that for $1<k<p$
$$
p\:\Big|\binom {p}{k}
$$
Thus 
$$
(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since I can not yet comment, I will post some hint here: A field is of characteristic $p$ if $x^p = i$ $\forall x \in E$ where $i$ is the identity of the field. In this case, since you are dealing with addition, you have $px = 0$ $\forall x \in E$

However, you don't really need to know what a characteristic is to show this is a homomorphism. Since $E$ is a field (and thus commutative), you know that $(xy)^p = x^py^p$, otherwise it would flip.

For the addition case, use binomial expansion $(x+y)^p = x^p$ + ${p}\choose{1}$ $x^{p-1}y$ + ... + ${p}\choose{p-1}$ $xy^{p-1} + y^p$. If you expand out the $p$ choose whatever, $p$ will divide those coefficients and thus, since this is a field of characteristic $p$, those coefficients will be $0$, and you are only left with $x^p + y^p$.

Comment: That definition helps a lot and according to the commentor above, apparently I don't need it but my problem then is showing that what you said is true. Could I just say that since it is a field, it follows all the axioms so then $f(x+y) = (x+y)^p = x^p + y^p$? How can I be sure that this is true?

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Dealing with the middle terms confused me.